# Apache failed to make http response

Tags: apache, http

I want to build a website with httpd official docker image on my CentOS server. However, I encountered a weird problem. On my CentOS server, `wget http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx` works properly. But on my laptop, I can connect to the server but can not get any http response:

```
--2022-01-19 22:55:33--  http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/
Connecting to xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response...
```

I didn't modify the configuration file `httpd.conf`. No idea why it doesn't work remotely. Can anyone help me to solve the problem? You'll have my gratitude. I'll leave the compose file below.

```
services:
  httpd:
    image: httpd:2.4
    network_mode: host
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the issue could be on the remote server as the connection has been established at TCP level, you will need to wait what HTTP status code returns.

Also you can use [Wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org/docs/wsug_html_chunked/ChCapPrerequisitesSection.html) to capture the traffic and then follow the TCP stream to see the HTTP conversation.

So you can debug the tcp stream in live or saving the traffic output from your server at a file (example.pcap)  and save it,  then you can open it with Wireshark to see what happens between the server an your client.

Here is an example about how to start a capture in your server:

Open 2 terminals: in the first, ssh to your server and type:

```
# tcpdump -vv -s0 tcp port 80 -w /tmp/example.pcap
```

(you can also append and source host <client_IP> to filter junk requests and to review if the firewall is filtering your request SYN , ACK)

and in the second, use wget to browse your website, reproduce this problem and switch to the first terminal and press Ctrl+C.

Copy this .pcap file to the client and open with Wireshark to see what happens.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I tried to capture packets from my laptop. The server acknowledged HTTP request but didn't reply any data.

Comment: However, on the server side, I captured different packets. Clients resent SYN packets several times. The SYN ACK packet was "Communication administratively filtered". I turned off firewalld and then it works.